# I get too many results when compile

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hey guys i have this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_FONO (P_COD IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
V_FONO NUMBER(10);

BEGIN
SELECT
'9'||SUBSTR(CELULAR,4,1)||SUBSTR(CELULAR,7,3)||SUBSTR(CELULAR,-4,14)
INTO V_FONO
FROM PERSONA
JOIN CLIENTE USING(RUT)
WHERE COD_CLIENTE = P_COD;

RETURN V_FONO;

END;
```

and when i am going to test this i get too many results and i only want one

```
select fn_fono(1) FROM PERSONA;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You selected "from persona", so your query is returning a result for every row in the persona table. Because you put p_cod=>1 you get the same result back for every row.

Since your query is fully defined inside your function there is no need to reference any of the tables *outside* the function call. It is typical to use the pseudo-table "dual" when making a function call outside of a PL/SQL block:

```
select fn_fono(1) from dual;
```

If referencing the function inside another procedure or PL/SQL block, you would do something like this:

```
l_fono := fn_fono(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example the function gets called for each of the rows present in the table PERSONA.  if you need it to be run exactly once you would do as follows

```
select fn_fono(1) FROM PERSONA where rownum=1;
```

Comment: Better to avoid having Oracle touch the persona table unnecessarily, as it no reference to it is required in the top-level query (i.e. outside the function call).